# calculate standard deviation and plot the curving fit using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to write a pyhon code to analysis the standard deviation of each month in a 100 years data  from the web page (http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/202_EN.htm).

```
  datum  m_ta m_tax     m_taxd m_tan     m_tand
------- ----- ----- ---------- ----- ----------
1901-01  -4.7   5.0 1901-01-23 -12.2 1901-01-10
1901-02  -2.1   3.5 1901-02-06  -7.9 1901-02-15
1901-03   5.8  13.5 1901-03-20   0.6 1901-03-01
1901-04  11.6  18.2 1901-04-10   7.4 1901-04-23
1901-05  16.8  22.5 1901-05-31  12.2 1901-05-05
1901-06  21.0  24.8 1901-06-03  14.6 1901-06-17
1901-07  22.4  27.4 1901-07-30  16.9 1901-07-04
1901-08  20.7  25.9 1901-08-01  14.7 1901-08-29
....
```

The standard deviation code that I wrote is

```
def sd(x):
    l = pd.DataFrame()
    for e in range(1, 13): 
            r = x[x.index.str.contains("-" + str(e).zfill(2))] 
            l = l.append(r.std().to_frame().transpose(), ignore_index=True) 

    return l

standard = sd(df)
```

Here I want to plot the curving fit of `m_ta` to the data itself. Could somebody please help me how I can  plot  it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Yakym for providing the method to load the data as `df`.

Once that is obtained, you can extract the month and use it for grouping:

```
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['monthly_mean'] = df.groupby('month').m_ta.transform('mean')
df['monthly_std'] = df.groupby('month').m_ta.transform('std')
```

Because there is too much data to view in one chart, you may want to treat each month's data as a separate dataframe.  I've used a dictionary comprehension to do just that.

```
dfs = {m: df.loc[df.month == m, :] for m in df.month.unique()}
```

Now you can look at the results for each month in isolation.  Here, for example, is January.

```
n = 1
dfs[n].m_ta.plot(title='Month {0}'.format(n));
dfs[n].monthly_mean.plot();
(dfs[n].monthly_mean + dfs[n].monthly_std).plot();
(dfs[n].monthly_mean - dfs[n].monthly_std).plot()
```

[image]

Comment: @Alexander....Thank you so much. Here, did you plot for all m_ta, m_tax and m_tan?

Comment: No, this is just `m_ta`.  It appears that `m_tax` and `m_tan` could be the max and min values respectively for the given month.  `m_ta`:  monthly mean temperature, `m_tax`: the daily maximum mean temperature in the month, `m_tan`: the daily minimum mean temperature in the month

Answer (score 2):

A popular plotting library is `matplotlib`, and `pandas` has a convenient interface. To have a line plot, you can simply call `df.column_name.plot()`.

Anyway, hopefully this helps:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

# GET THE DATA
# body > div > pre > font
tree = html.fromstring(requests.get('http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/202_EN.htm').text)
lines = [l.text.split() for l in tree.xpath('//body/div/pre/font')]

# IMPORT DATA INTO PANDAS
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(lines[2:], columns = lines[0]).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df['datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datum, format='%Y-%m')
df = df.set_index('datum')

print 'Standard deviation of m_ta: %f' % df.m_ta.std()

# PLOT
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df.m_ta.plot()
plt.show()
```

std is 7.962143, here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks . I understand the graph for std, but still I stuck on curve fitting.

Comment: I think I misread the question. Anyways, @Alexander has closed the issue.